# UV Mirroring after UV Sculpting

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, mirror

[image]
How do you mirror one side to the other topology after UV sculpting?
My object already has many shape keys. Is there a solution other than how to apply the mirror modifier?

Comment: there may be another solution but mine would be to delete that side of the mesh that has old uv, mirror your object with mirror modifier and new mirrored part will have this same UV you created... but that only works if your model is symmetrized at this moment